# How to solve the differential equation ${\rm d}f_p(v) = A(p,v) f(p)$ in a manifold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f:M\to \Bbb R$ be smooth, such that  $${\rm d}f_p(v) = A(p,v) f(p), $$for all $v\in T_pM$, for some smooth coefficient  $A$. How to solve this equation rigorously? I know the answer should be of the form $f(p) = ce^{\lambda(p)} $ for some $c\in \Bbb R$ and $\lambda:M\to \Bbb R$ smooth.

I have a few ideas but they all feel like hand-waving. Sort as "let's solve for $f\circ \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is arbitrary" (say.. $(f\circ\alpha)'(t) = A(\alpha'(t)) (f\circ\alpha)(t)$ has solutions of the form $f(\alpha(t)) = ce^{\lambda(t)}$, then write $p$ instead of $t$), but needless to say, I'm unhappy with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is as follows: As mentioned in the answer of @EclipseSun, you have to assume that $A(p,v)$ is linear in $v$. Then this defines a one-form, let me call it $\alpha$, and your  equation becomes $df= f\alpha$. Assuming that $f$ is non-zero, you can write this as $\frac{df}{f}=\alpha$, i.e. as $d\log(f)=\alpha$. Thus you get a necessary condition for existence of a solution, namely $d\alpha=0$, i.e. $\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x^j}=\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x^i}$ for all $i$ and $j$. If this is satsified, then locally $\alpha=d\lambda$ for a smooth function $\lambda$ (which is determined up to an additive constant). This gives a solution of the expected form $f(x)=Ce^{\lambda(x)}$. If you are looking for global solutions, you need that in addition to $d\alpha=0$ the class of $\alpha$ in the first de-Rham cohomology is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Write in local coordinates $(U;x^i)$,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}=A_i(x)f(x),$$

where $A_i$'s are smooth. You can solve the system of PDEs if and only if [Frobenius conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)) hold.

Also, $A(p,v)$ should be linear in $v$.

Comment: I'm familiar with Frobenius, but $f$ is real-valued, so I think we'll only have one equation, and not a system. (Maybe I'm missing something obvious?)

Comment: Since you want it holds for all $v\in T_pM$, at least it should hold for $v=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots, \dim M$.

Comment: Ah. I'd expect something neat, but you're right, thanks.